# How can I log in to Webmin if it doesn't accept/I can't remember my user details?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webmin

I installed webmin, and I tried to access it with my account (not root, but able to sudo) and I always got

> login failed.

Now I have

> Access Denied

even to my login page for too many tries. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default for Webmin is set at 5 attempts and then a lockout is set for 60 seconds. So if you haven't changed these defaults, you should be able to try again in 60 seconds.

The login details should be what you supplied during installation. If you somehow don't remember these, try the below steps.

- If you are running a RedHat distribution (i.e. Fedora, CentOS, Gentoo), enter the following command with root or `sudo`:

  ```
  /usr/libexec/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin username password
  ```
- If you are running a Debian distribution (i.e. Ubuntu like you), enter the following command with root or `sudo`:

  ```
  /usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin username password
  ```

Of course the user you specify will need to be a valid user in the Webmin config. This will not work for creating new Webmin users.

Comment: i will accept your answer, but i still don't know why i couldn't login with my administrator account. I had to change root's password, and login with root. Thanks anyway

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez Webmin users have to be created in the Webmin administration. You can't just use any system user to log in.